# Form Entity Type Checkboxes Does Not Remove Unchecked Items

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I am using two entities having a ManyToMany relation, Jobsite having a workers property and vice versa. I have a form JobsiteType which propose a list of workers to select or not, it works quite welle with multiple select : select or unselect are well propagated in the db, but it does not work when using checkboxes : unselect item does not remove it from relation table.
I am using Symfony v 2.8, here is few details :

// Entity Jobsite

```
class Jobsite {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserWorker", inversedBy="jobsites", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="jobsite_worker")
     */
    protected $workers;
...
```

// Entity Worker

```
class UserWorker {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Jobsite", mappedBy="workers", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $jobsites;
    ...
```

// JobsiteType

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        ...
        $builder
            ->add('workers', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:UserWorker',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choices_as_values' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,// if false, multiple select is working almost well !
                'label' => 'label.workers',
                'required' => false,
                'choices' => $workers,// list of possible workers
            ))
...
```

So does anybody knows what is wrong with checkboxes style (multiple + expanded) ? I know that unchecked inputs send nothing, so does it means I have to manually loop trough workers in a form event to apply the right changes ? Well I notice also that it does not work with multiple select box when no item is selected, it is probably related to the same 'nothing sended if empty' effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for multiple select, it is needed to check if the field is set, if not apply an empty array as the field data, then data propagation is ok, empty set will remove items from the relation table...
But it does not resolve multiple checkboxes :(

```
    $builder
        ...
        ->addEventListener( FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();

                // the trick : allow empty selection (reset list)
                if(!isset($data['workers'])){   $data['workers'] = [];}

                $event->setData($data);
            }
        )
```

## EDIT RIGHT ANSWER

So simple as a submit flag that remove empty things

```
// contoller
$form->submit($request, true);// second arg true is the trick
```